# How to check if a date reached or expired for every year

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date field that only has the month and the date say, 02/03 `(dd/mm)`. For every year when the date reaches '2nd of march' I want to generate an alert. Usually we can do date comparison like this:

```js
var mdate='01-04-2010';
date = Date.parse(mdate.split('-')[1]+'-'+mdate.split('-')[0]+'-'+mdate.split('-')[2]);
if (parseInt(date) < parseInt(Date.now()))
{
    alert('small');
} else {
    alert('big');
}
```

Now I have dd/mm and that should be checked **every day** and at **each year when it reaches that particular date I need to generate an alert**.

Can some one please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var today = new Date();
if (parseInt(today.getDate()) == 2 && parseInt(today.getMonth()) == 2) {
   alert('It is 2nd of march');
}
```

Comment: parseInt(today.getMonth()) is returning 3 for moth of april? What should I do for it? Can you please help me?@Sanjay Kumar N S

Comment: Yes. 0 for Jan, 1 for Feb, likewise 3 for April

Comment: So if i need to check for jan i should use parseInt(today.getMonth()) == 0 ?@Sanjay Kumar N S